# How to add exsiting project to git bare repository?

Tags: php, eclipse, git, deployment, continuous-deployment

I am trying to setup git for automatic deployment. Here is what I am doing..

1. I have created one empty bare repository on my repos server which hosted on xyz.com.
2. Then in eclipse using EGit I have clone newly created bare repository.
3. On my local machine I have one php project.
4. Now I want to create 3 branches development, staging, production and want to add my project to development branch.

Maybe I am doing something wrong or missed something to setup. Can anyone please guide me for git setup?

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the 3 branches, you can do the following (using whatever names you prefer) from the git command line:

```
git checkout -b prod
git checkout -b stage
git checkout -b dev
```

To add your project to the dev branch, copy your project files into the git working directory on your filesystem - this will be the directory that contains the '.git' directory (i.e. not the '.git' directory itself).

Then from the command line run:

```
git status
```

which should give you a list of the files that you copied - they will be under the heading 'Untracked files:'.

Now run the following commands to add them to the dev branch (replacing "MyCommitMessage" with an appropriate commit message):

```
git add .
git commit -m "MyCommitMessage"
```

At this point you can use

```
git push --all
```

to synchronise the remote bare repository with what you have locally.

Comment: What I understand is that I should add 3 different branches to bare repository. So lets take an example that I have created 3 now. development, staging, production. Now I clone bare repository to my local machine. Now should I need to add my project to 3 of the branches or add project to development branch and merge development branch to staging and production?

Comment: Add the project files to one branch (dev) using the 'git add .' and 'git commit -m "MyCommitMessage"' commands, and then merge to the others. For the merging, use commands like: git checkout stage; git merge dev; git checkout prod; git merge stage; (which merges dev->stage and then stage->prod).

Comment: Thanks, will try out the way

Answer (score 0):

Since you have cloned from the hosted repository, you should have a git 'remote' configured called 'origin', which refers to your hosted repository.

When you work and commit on a local branch (e.g. master) you can push that to a branch on the other repository with `git push origin :'

```
git push origin master:development
```

This assuming you have a git command line client available. You should be able to do the same thing with your graphical client, the main concept is that you push a branch with a certain name to a branch with a certain name on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how comfortable you are with git command line, but since it's how I use it, here it goes:

1. instead of cloning your remote repo, go to your code folder and create a new local repo

   `git init`
2. commit something to your local master branch to proper init it

   `echo "first commit" >  README.txt`
   `git add README.txt`
   `git commit -m "first commit"`
3. now you can create your three branchs

   `git branch development`
   `git branch staging`
   `git branch production`
4. change to the development branch, and add all your code

   `git checkout development`
   `git add .`
   `git commit -m "code commit"`
5. for last, add your remote repository and push your branchs

   `git remote add origin <url_to_your_remote_repo>`
   `git push -u origin --all`

Comment: What I understand is that I should add 3 different branches to bare repository. So lets take an example that I have created 3 now. development, staging, production. Now I clone bare repository to my local machine. Now should I need to add my project to 3 of the branches or add project to development branch and merge development branch to staging and production?

Comment: @SangamAngre You should commit your code to one of the branches and either merge to the other or you could create the others from the first one. So, you would just create a dev branch, commit your code, and then create the other two branches

Comment: ohk. I will definitely try your way and will get back to you soon. Thanks for your help